# how to manually force VoiceOver/TalkBack to speak in React Native

Tags: react-native, voiceover, talkback

I am working on a React Native application which which uses slider components. These Slider components currently are not very accessible. When focused by a Screen Reader or Talkback the only thing that is read out loud is the accessibility label.

I would like to try and implement a slider that can behave like sliders in default iOS, where moving the slider will cause VoiceOver to constantly read out the value of the slider as it's being adjusted. Is it possible to trigger VoiceOver or Talkback directly in a function so I could implement something like this

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the same issue :(

Comment: unfortunately not, it's incredibly frustrating. It seems like in general a11y support for react-native is lacking

Answer (score 1):

I am a little late to the game but hopefully this will help someone else looking for a solution.
Accessibility announcements can be made using the [AccessibilityInfo](https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibilityinfo) API. The specific function used for announcements is [announceForAccessibility](https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibilityinfo#announceforaccessibility), like so:

```
AccessibilityInfo.announceForAccessibility(`Slider moved to ${value}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're not using a native iOS `UISlider` or `UIProgressView`?  You can announce notifications in Voiceover using [`UIAccessibilityPostNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1615194-uiaccessibilitypostnotification?changes=__1_1&language=objc) and pass it a string or an object.

Android usually uses a `<SeekBar>` for sliders.  If not using those, then announcements can be made via [`android:accessibilityLiveRegion`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:accessibilityLiveRegion) or [`announceForAccessibility`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#announceForAccessibility(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: The author stated specifically that the context is react native. Why would you post a native ios solution?

Comment: Because all possible solutions should be explored. If it can’t be done in react, then fall back to native code.  Do you have anything constructive to add?  No other solutions have been posted. Feel free to post an alternative.

Comment: Nice try, but no. Most RN devs I know don't ever walk on the native side of code. In some cases, such a solution wouldn't even be allowed because QA would need to know how to test it. I wouldn't suggest a RN solution to an ios question. Best to not pose ios solutions in an RN post.

Comment: Nice try for what? I'm not following your logic for trying something. If you're a RN dev, I assume you've heard of native modules? It's perfectly valid to call iOS (or Android) native functions.